# Launch and terminate shiny app through terminal

Tags: r, terminal, shiny

How can I launch the Shiny App, "my_shiny" through the terminal.

Also, how do I terminate or close the app through the terminal only.

Comment: Have a look here, using .bat file
http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/3269_a6682dfda37e411fb5e0e6699495cdc4.html

Comment: How do I close the App

Comment: research how to use `taskkill`

Answer (score 20):

Try this:

```
Rscript -e 'library(methods); shiny::runApp("my_shiny/", launch.browser = TRUE)'
```

Answer (score 5):

Or shorter:

```
R -e "shiny::runApp('my_shiny')"
```

If you want to specify a port:

```
R -e "shiny::runApp('my_shiny', port = 3838)"
```

As with most other commands, you can interrupt the process with `Ctr`+ `C`.

---

### Addendum

I wrote this line

```
R -e "shiny::runApp('my_shiny', port = 3838)"
```

into a shell script called, e.g., `run.sh` to conveniently run it from the shell as `sh ./run.sh`. :)