# Run Shiny App from Shortcut Windows 10

Tags: r, shiny, windows-10

I'm trying to create a shortcut on the desktop to run a Shiny app. I am stuck on creating a batch file to execute this and after scouring the web, I still haven't been able to get it to work.

I am on Windows 10.

At the moment I have a folder on the desktop called "test" with contents:

```
ui.R
server.R
run.R
test.bat
```

Within test.bat, I have:
`"path to R.exe" CMD BATCH "path to my r script"`

I double click on test.bat, and it flashes a window before closing.

How can I get this to work? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35986731/680068

Answer (score 11):

Probably you have solved it, but for someone who has the same question, I'm posting what worked for me. I created a .bat file like this:

```
"path/to/R.exe" -e "shiny::runApp('path/to/shinyAppFolder', launch.browser = TRUE)"
```

But I think this works as well:

```
"path/to/R.exe" -e "path/to/run.R"
```

You can always add a line with the `pause` command to your batch file so you can see whats going wrong with the script

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the R working directory to the folder containing your shiny files; or explicitly specify the path in your call to `runApp()`.

Something like this:

**test.bat**

```
"path/to/Rscript.exe" "path/to/run.R"
```

**run.R**

```
library(shiny)
setwd("c:/users/username/Desktop/test")
runApp()
```