# Launch R shinyapp package through terminal

Tags: r, windows, shiny

I have a shinyapp written as a standard R package, call `ShinyPick`.

I can start the app using the R code: `ShinyPick::run_app()`.

I am trying to create a shortcut to run the app.

Here is my bat file:

```
@echo off
Set R="path/to/R.exe"
Rscript -e "ShinyPick::run_app()"

exit 0
```

But it does not work. I don't know where the problem is.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Launch and terminate shiny app through terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35986731/launch-and-terminate-shiny-app-through-terminal)

Comment: What is `ShinyPick`?  I've only ever used the form:  `"C:\[path to R bin folder]\Rscript.exe" -e "shiny::runApp('[appname]', launch.browser = TRUE)"` - I suspect you need to name the app to run and include `launch.browser'

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen ShinyPick is my Shiny app written in a standard R package. it is not an app folder. That's why `"shiny::runApp('[appname]', launch.browser = TRUE)"` does not work for me. but I think running a package should be easier.

Comment: @smartse Thanks a lot for your help. I have check that link. but my shiny is an R package, it is not a folder, therefore the provided solutions does not work in my case.

Comment: So what? I have an app as a package too and it runs fine `Rscript -e 'library(methods); <library>::<run_app_function>()`

Comment: Can you share your `run_app()` function?

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen sure. it is a standard golem framework: run_app <- function(
  onStart = NULL,
  options = list(),
  enableBookmarking = NULL,
  uiPattern = "/",
  ...
) {
  with_golem_options(
    app = shinyApp(
      ui = app_ui,
      server = app_server,
      onStart = onStart,
      options = options,
      enableBookmarking = enableBookmarking,
      uiPattern = uiPattern
    ),
    golem_opts = list(...)
  )
}

Comment: It's importing `methods` - for some reason that isn't loaded by default when run from the command line

Comment: @smartse FYI, the `library(methods)` call is unnecessary. Packages are self-contained.

Comment: I don't think it SHOULD be required, but can you please try including `options=list(launch.browser=TRUE)` as an argument to `run_app()` in the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `options=list(launch.browser=TRUE)` as an argument to `run_app()` in the command line

Comment: To be clear, setting this option is not necessary. The application will run perfectly file without it, it just won’t automatically open a new session in the default browser; the user has to do that manually.

Comment: Yes - I included this because it fixed the 'expected' behaviour for this user, but @KonradRudolph you're of course right that the app was presumably running perfectly fine before.